# What locus is formed by $|z-4i|-|z+4i|=10$ in complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

What locus is formed by $|z-4i|-|z+4i|=10$ in complex plane?

I know the locus formed by $|z-4i|+|z+4i|=10$, which is an ellipse, but this involves subtraction. I tried to simplify this in the following way: $$\left(\sqrt{x^2 + (y - 4)^2} - \sqrt{x^2 + (y + 4)^2}\right) - 10 = 0,$$ but I cannot find the answer for $x$, $y$ in real numbers.

Comment: The set of points for which the difference between the distances of said point with other two fixed point (foci) is a constant? It is a hyperbola.

Comment: Image of any cuirve in the Argand  plane $ (x,y)$ is always w.r.t.o some line, this line/curve is most crucial..Here no suc line or curve is mentioned.

Comment: The term you were looking for is *locus*. An *image* is the value returned by a function. A *locus* is the set of all points whose locations are determined by stated conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way:

- $|z-a|=r$ gives you a circle of radius $r$ centered at $a$. That is, it is all of the points of distance $r$ from $a$.
- Your equation is of the form $|z-a|-|z-b|=d$ where $a=4i$, $b=-4i$, $d=10$.
- Read it aloud: the set of $z$ that satisfy this equation are the points $z$ such that the difference of their distances from $a$ and $b$ is $d$.

This last bit - the set of points whose difference of distances from two distinct points is fixed - is precisely the characterization of a hyperbola. This is all you need to do in order to realize it is such.

Comment: Image of any cuirve in the Argand  plane $ (x,y)$ is always w.r.t.o some line, this line/curve is most crucial..Here no such curve.line is mentiones!

Comment: But how can I find the equation of this curve